# flexible centered page

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [flexible or centered page HTML CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203738/flexible-or-centered-page-html-css)

I need a flexible or centered page design that works even for users with screen resolutions of 800*600. (CSS + HTML)

Should I use % or px for width and height?

Could you please give any example link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="content">
</div>

#content {
  width:800px; (or width: 80%;)
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/UyUFa/

Comment: what about height? Should I write height:600px as well?

Comment: Height should expend with content? no need to specify.