# flexible or centered page HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I have to use a flexible or centered page design that works even for users screen resolutions of 800*600. When I make my page smaller, the elements are moving and changing their positions. Is it normal for flexible or centered page? If it is not how is supposed to be?

CSS code for the page;

```
body {
             margin-left: auto;
             margin-right: auto;
             text-align:center;}

 div.header {
     padding-top: 1pc;
     text-align:center;
     width:100%;
     color: #000000;}

 div.header h1 {
color: #493831;
padding-bottom: 30px;
margin: 0;}

 div.menu { 
    list-style:none; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background:#FBB117;} 
 div.menu ul{ 
    font-size:14px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    width: 100px 
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;} 
 div.menu li{ 
    display:inline; } 
 div.menu li a{ 
    text-decoration:none; 
    padding:7px 0; 
    width:100px; 
    background:#FBB117; 
    color:#4C4646; 
    float:left; 
    text-align:center; 
    border-left:1px solid #fff;}  
 div.menu li a:hover{ 
    background:#a2b3a1; 
    color:#000 } 


 div.sidebar {
     padding-top: 2pc;
     margin-right: 15%;
     margin-left: 15px;
     text-align:center;
     float: right;
     width: 200px;
     color: #000000;
     list-style:none; }
 div.sidebar ul{
     font-size:14px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto; 
     margin-top: 3px;
     margin-bottom: 3px;
     padding:0;
     list-style: none;
     display:inline-block;  }
 div.sidebar li{
     display:inline; }
 div.sidebar li a{ 
    text-decoration:none; 
    padding:10px 0; 
    width:100%; 
    background:#FBB117; 
    color:#4C4646; 
    float:right; 
    text-align:center; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;}  
 div.sidebar li a:hover{ 
    background:#a2b3a1; 
    color:#000 } 

 div.content {
     width:80%;
     padding-top: 2pc;
     text-align:left;
     margin-left: 15%;
     margin-right: 300px;
     color: #000000 }
 div.content p {
font-weight: lighter;
color: #493831;
padding-bottom: 30px;
margin: 0;}


 div img.bw {
     float:left;
     margin-right:15px;
     width:200px;
     height:200px; }

 div img.map {
     float:right;
     margin-right:15px;
     width:300px;
     height:100px; }

 div.footer {
     padding: 100px;
     text-align:center;
     height: 100px;
     color: #000000 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195852/flexible-centered-page isnt this the same question ?

Comment: You're missing the first part of your CSS, haven't provided the HTML, and your question is unclear. Elements are moving how? Which elements? You'll need to provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or other demo.

Comment: Kinda but I am not sure how a centered and flexible page is. I ans make the page smaller, everything can change their positions. Is it normal for a flexible or centered page? Thanks.

Comment: Moving how? They change their position. For example a picture is supposed to be left hand side near text but when I shrink the page, the picture's position is under the text. Another example; the menu is at the center, when I shrink the page, the menu becomes double line menu. I am asking all these things are normal for flexible page design? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If things won't fit in their original places, sounds pretty plausible to me that they would go into another line cause otherwise they would push through their parent container, right? **Actual 'working' example of the _problem_ tells us more than a thousand words**

Comment: http://stunningcss3.com/code/bakery/index.html for example. When you shrink the page, menu will be double lined. But when you shrink the page a lot, the pictures will change their position but be smaller size. But in my page, picture size is always same, (does it mean pictures are not flexible?) I am very confused. Should I make them flexible to make my page flexible? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please do not repost questions. If you have new information to add to an existing question, use the edit link to add it.

Answer (score 0):

The best method to control what is going on with your page when trying to limit size restrictions is to assign different stylesheets to change the site subject to resolution. These will be for users that are accessing your site using different resolutions.

http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/: link provided

This issue has troubled many designers for a long time and back in the 90s when fluid layouts were all the rage this problem had to be overcome.

Bare in mind that with the development and growing usage of mobile devices to view webpages, making a mobile version of your site then this is also the method to take.

In doing this you are applying a totally new layout of your webpages to make best use of the available space. Also, if a users browser does not support this declaration then they will still be able to view your site.... Everyone is a winner.